# Get a tree with MongoDB query (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Is there any easy way to get a tree in mongoose? Let's consider following example:

```
categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name    : {type: String, required: true},
    parent  : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category'}
})
```

I have a category that can have a lot of children (sub-categories), and these children can have a lot of children (sub-sub-categories) and so on...

As far as it's quite easy to build such structure and modify it, it's quite hard for me to retrieve that structure.
I did it in very bad way scanning the collection recursively, but I guess there can be a better way to do that.

In SQL it's quite easy to achieve that and I am wondering if there is a good way to do that in mongodb.

Note: This schema may be changed if needed.

Comment: Seems like a hammer/screwdriver situation. Is there a reason you must use MongoDB rather than a relational DB or a NoSQL DB that's better suited to trees (eg Neo4j)?

Comment: dont know about moongoose but mongoDB got https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/  function. maybe it can help you